# Edits into List Item do not save

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, custom-list

I found many topics & answers with something similar not what I need.  I have a list and multiple people have access to.  I seem to be the only one having the issues.  I checked permissions and I have the same as others.  Here is the problem.  The custom list when I add an item it works.  But when I edit one of the columns (multiple line column) and click save the edits do not save.  This does not happen with anyone else.  There is not a required column either.  Can someone help me?

Comment: any error message that you get ? either on UI or console ?

Comment: Strange SharePoint!!!
Please post the error(if any) you are getting while editing the list item.

Comment: Its the oddest thing, but I am not receiving any errors.  I wish I would that would make my troubleshooting easier

Comment: Is there any script on the form or workflow running on the list?

Comment: @harshalgite No script and no running workflows

Comment: @SharePointLady  did you ever find a solution for this?  i'm more or less dealing with the exact same issue in a large-ish SPO list.  thx!